# sqlcmd turn off text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sqlcmd that I'm outputting results to a text file. The first cmd is a USE mydatabase command and it logs that info in the output file that it "Changed database context to mydatabase"

How do I turn that off in the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps related to your problem is the following [link](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/893899-changed-database-context-xxxx)

> using SP_SEND_DBMAIL, I just needed to
>   use the parameter
>   "@execute_query_database=XXXXX";

or pass the -m flag as mentioned [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=92052)

```
check SQLCMDERRORLEVEL and the -m flag passed to sqlcmd.

C:\>sqlcmd -Q "use master" -E
Changed database context to 'master'.

C:\>sqlcmd -Q "use master" -E -m 1

C:\>
```